# Function to limit number of custom post types on homepage - TwentyTen

Tags: custom-post-types, functions, query, homepage, theme-twenty-ten

here is the deal...

I got hold of this piece of code to change the default post type shown on my TwentyTen child theme's homepage. It works like a charm when I add this code to the functions.php file, but I would like to also limit the number of posts to 1 (or 2) instead of the default 10 as in "Settings" section.

What can I add to the code below so that it display only 1 (or 2) Tours?

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'add_tours_post_type_to_query' );
function add_tours_post_type_to_query( $query ) {
if ( is_home() && $query->is_main_query() )
$query->set( 'post_type', array( 'tours' ) );
return $query;
}
```

I hope I can get some help here! Many thanks.

UPDATE:
I pasting here how I manage to filter by category as well...

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'add_tours_post_type_to_query' );

function add_tours_post_type_to_query( $query ) {

if ( is_home() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
    $query->set( 'posts_per_page', 1 );
    $query->set( 'category_name', 'featured_tour' );
    $query->set( 'post_type', array( 'tours' ) );
}
return $query;
}
```

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'add_tours_post_type_to_query' );

function add_tours_post_type_to_query( $query ) {

  if ( is_home() && $query->is_main_query() ){
    $query->set( 'post_type', array( 'tours' ) );
    $query->set( 'posts_per_page', 1 );
  }

  return $query;
}
```

For the future the [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/) can be your friend. Exactly this [is explained there](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts#Changing_the_number_of_posts_per_page.2C_by_post_type).

Comment: Beat me by 12 secs. ;) +1

Comment: Awesome! you make it look so simple... I'm a bit of a beginner  but getting my way into it. Can we filter by category by any chance? i.e. Featured Tours

Comment: This is why I added the link to the source. Just scroll a liiittle bit upwards. Also for the future: Either edit your original question or ask a new one if you have follow up questions. And use search - these are pretty standard issues.

Answer (score 0):

See the [`posts_per_page`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Pagination_Parameters) query var.

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'add_tours_post_type_to_query' );

function add_tours_post_type_to_query( $query ) {

    if ( is_home() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
        $query->set( 'post_type', array( 'tours' ) );
        $query->set( 'posts_per_page', 2 );
    }

    return $query;
}
```

Comment: Awesome! you make it look so simple... I'm a bit of a beginner but getting my way into it. Can we filter by category by any chance? i.e. Featured Tours